# C++ Passing a reference variable to the thread in g++-4.7.4

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc, g++

I need to start a thread passing complex parameters (std::thread<>) as a parameter when the thread starts. I´m using `std::ref. This code works fine with updated environments (g++-4.8.2 running on Ubuntu).

Now I have to compile this same code in a old compiler (g++4.7.4) and I´m getting errors.

The code is shown below, as well as the error:

**ReaderThread.hpp**

```
class ReaderThread {
    void start(Reader reader, SyncController &syncController);
}
```

**ReaderThread.cpp**

```
void ReaderThread::start(Reader reader, SyncController &syncController)
{

        Do something...
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{

    ...do stuff...

    /* 
     * Create and start the reader thread. The created object must live
     * during the whole thread life.
     * std::ref is used to pass as reference
     */
    myReader = ReaderFactory(params);

    std::shared_ptr<ReaderThread> ptr(new ReaderThread); 
    std::thread th(&ReaderThread::start, ptr, myReader, std::ref(syncController));


    ...do other stuff...
}
```

ERROR:

```
In file included from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/bits/move.h:57:0,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_pair.h:61,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/bits/stl_algobase.h:65,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/bits/char_traits.h:41,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/ios:41,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/ostream:40,
                 from /usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/iostream:40,
                 from ./main.cpp:11:
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/type_traits: In instantiation of 'struct std::_Result_of_impl<false, false, std::_Mem_fn<void (ReaderThread::*)(Reader, SyncController&)>, std::shared_ptr<ReaderThread>, Reader, std::reference_wrapper<SyncController> >':
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/type_traits:1857:12:   required from 'class std::result_of<std::_Mem_fn<void (ReaderThread::*)(Reader, SyncController&)>(std::shared_ptr<ReaderThread>, Reader, std::reference_wrapper<SyncController>)>'
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/functional:1563:61:   required from 'struct std::_Bind_simple<std::_Mem_fn<void (ReaderThread::*)(Reader, SyncController&)>(std::shared_ptr<aeirtuthread::ReaderThread>, Reader, std::reference_wrapper<SyncController>)>'
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/thread:133:9:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (ReaderThread::*)(Reader, SyncController&); _Args = {std::shared_ptr<ReaderThread>&, Reader&, std::reference_wrapper<SyncController>}]'
./aeirtu/aeirtu/main.cpp:155:96:   required from here
/usr/gcc-4.7.4/lib/gcc/i586-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.4/../../../../include/c++/4.7.4/type_traits:1834:9: error: no match for call to '(std::_Mem_fn<void (ReaderThread::*)(Reader, SyncController&)>) (std::shared_ptr<ReaderThread>, Reader, std::reference_wrapper<SyncController>)'
```

I can´t find out if this error is being caused by the use of `std::ref` on older compilers or from something different.

Help appreciated fo find a fix that would be supported by 4.7.4 and compile my code.

Comment: while c++11 is almost fully supported in gcc 4.8.x, gcc 4.7.x missing few features. check here: https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Comment: Indeed, but I need to fix the code for compilation... help appreciated...

Comment: Use the pointer instead of the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gcc 4.7 doesn't seem to be able to handle shared_ptr (or unique_ptr for this matter) provided as an object. It works fine with natural pointer, though - so one possible solution would be to replace thread creation with following (if appropriate, of course):

```
std::thread th(&ReaderThread::start, &myThread, myReader, std::ref(syncController));
```

Now, if this is not feasible and true allocated pointers are needed, following is a replacement for your idea:

```
  std::thread th(
                 [ptr, &syncController, myReader] () {
                      ptr->start(myReader, syncController);
                 }
                );

}
```

In this example, synController is passed by reference, everything else by value, same way as in your post.

Comment: Replaced by a natural pointer and now it works fine... Anyway I will give a try to the 2nd suggestion as well... Thanks.

Comment: @Mendez, natural pointer, of course, is the most strightforward. The only caveat here is that if you need to manage lifecycle of your object, natural pointer will likely not do.